# Accessing SharedMailBox in Python from Outlook

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

I have this structure on my outlook
primary email
-Inbox
-Drafts
-SentItems
-Deleted Items

BotEmail(SharedEmailbox)
-Drafts
-Sent Items
-Deleted Item
-Specific Folder

I want to access my BotEmail Folder but unable to do it so, although i can access the primary email folder but whenever i try to access my sharedmailbox I got error **object not found** while primary mailbox folders are printed

```
import win32com.client


outlook_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook_app.GetNamespace("MAPI")


primary_email = 'primary@outlook.com'
shared_mailbox_email = 'databot1@outlook.com'

# Access the primary email account inbox
primary_inbox = namespace.Folders[primary_email].Folders['Inbox']
shared_mailbox= namespace.Folders[shared_mailbox_email].Folders['Inbox']


print("Folders in Primary Email Account:")
for folder in primary_inbox.Parent.Folders:
    print(folder.Name)



print("Folders in Primary Email Account:")
for folder in shared_mailbox.Parent.Folders:
    print(folder.Name)
```

How Can we access the folders of my sharedmailbox?

Tried MAPI exchangeLib and PyOutlook Library didn't get satisfactory results

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the folder you want is on the same level as the delegate Inbox, you can try

```py
subfolder = shared_mailbox.Parent.Folder['TheSubFolder']
```